# Probabilities after random assignment

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

I have 4 colors and I am going to assign them independently uniformly at random to 3 buckets. I am asked to find what is the probability that each bucket gets a different color.

My approach: I can solve the problem in a manual way to find probability to have exactly 2 repeating colors, and also having exactly 3 repeating colors.

I want to generalize this to having $n$ colors and $m < n$ buckets, but I am unsure how.

Comment: How many choices for the first bucket?  How many for the second (given the first choice)? and so on.

Comment: I can count that myself, but I want to generalize it

Comment: I didn't specify a number of buckets (or colors).  The same argument works for any numbers.

Comment: An equivalent count:  How many choices are there using distinct colors?  How many are there with no restriction?

Comment: Hmm, okay, but finding this seems like tidious procedure. I was thinking to use something like $1 - ({ n }\choose {m})$ directly.

Comment: So use the second method I mentioned.  Note that it is literally equivalent to the first one, but maybe it feels more natural.

Comment: My problem is trying to find a close formula for that. I understand the logic of both versions. But for instance in the reformulation - `How many choices are there using distinct colors` - could that be done with some binomial expression directly?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  I've given you two methods both of which yield (the same) closed formula.  Please show some effort.

Comment: @lulu I just put my attempt as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go through that, but I failed. I fixed my number of colors to be $C$. And started testing for different numbers of buckets.

- If there is one bucket trivially, with 100% chance, color is unique.
- For 2 buckets, there are $C^2$ possible combinations, out of which only $C$ are with repeating colors, this there are $C^2 - C$ good cases, and probability to get all colors to be unique is $\frac{(C-1)}{C}$.
- For 3 buckets, total of $C^3$ possible combinations. We need to remove all "groups" where there are 2 repeating or 3 elements - There are $C$ groups where all items are the same and $3C(C-1)$ groups with 2 repeating elements only, thus there are  $\frac{C^3 - 3C^2 +3C - C}{C^3} = \frac{(C-1)(C-2)}{C^2}$.

I am not confident with this step already, and this look similar to odds $\frac{1}{C \choose B}$, where C is the number of colors and $B$ is the number of buckets.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, it is good you have written an attempt, but you have posted it in the wrong place, I'd say. I suggest posting this as part of your question instead (by clicking "Edit" above).

Comment: Don't try to subtract bad cases, there are too many and they are hard to describe.  Just count the good cases.  For two buckets, there are $C$ choices for the first and then $C-1$ choices for the second.  Thus the answer in that case is $\frac {C(C-1)}{C^2}$ which you can reduce to $\frac {C-1}C$ to match your result.  The direct counting method works equally well in all cases.

Comment: ahaa, now I get it, for i buckets then must be $\frac{(C-1)(C-2)\dots(C-i)}{C^i}$

Comment: Well, you either need the extra $C$ in he numerator or take one off of the denominator.  Bust basically correct.